# How do I give a form a specific ID for a cart when it's appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a webpage where, if you click on a product name, it opens up the description of the product as well as a form which says 'Add to cart'. This doesn't work.

The same form appears on all of my products so no matter which product I select, it doesn't specify which product I want to add to cart as it's appended to all of the products.

I want it to work so that I can click on a product name, the description and form pops up on the same page (this part is working) but then when I change the quantity to a number then click 'Add to cart' on the form, it has its own unique identifier where I'll actually be able to input it into the cart as its own product.

This is what I have so far, I just haven't created the code for my actual cart yet but as I know that I'm doing something wrong so far as I can see no matter the form I'm using in any product, the output is the same no matter the product.

```js
function drawPage() {
  $.get('/products', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var prod = data.products;

    for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
      var el = document.createElement('P');
      el.innerHTML = prod[i].name;
      el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.textContent);
        for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
          if (prod[i].name == event.target.textContent) {
            $('#pro').html('');
            $('#pro').html(prod[i].name +
              prod[i].description + '<img src=' + prod[i].image_url + '>' + "Price: " +
              prod[i].unit_cost);

            $("#pro").append(
              $("<form/>", {
                action: '#',
                method: '#'
              }).append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'number',
                id: 'pro',
                name: 'productname',
                placeholder: 'Quantity'
              }), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
                type: 'submit',
                id: 'submit',
                value: 'Add to Cart'
              }))
            )
          }
        }
      })
      $('#app').append(el);
    }
  })
}

document.addEventListener('load', drawPage());
```

```html
<div id="cart-container">
  <h1>My Cart</h1>
  <table id="myCart" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Item name</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none; border-top: 2px solid black">
      <td colspan="3">Subtotal</td>
      <td class="right subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Aside from the issue in the question, your last line of code needs to be `document.addEventListener('load', drawPage);` as you need to pass the *reference* of `drawPage` to the handler, not the *result* of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I just assume that your prodcuts are a couple of json formatted objects and then u can just pass them around :

```
var products = [
{id: 1, name: 'Product 1', desc: 'product 1 desc'},
{id: 2, name: 'Product 2', desc: 'product 2 desc'},
{id: 3, name: 'Product 3', desc: 'product 3 desc'},
{id: 4, name: 'Product 4', desc: 'product 4 desc'},
];

$.each(products, function() {
    addProduct(this);
});

function addProduct(product) {
    var link = $('<button></button>').text(product.name);
    link.on('click', function(){
        loadProduct(product);
    });
    $('#products').append(link);
}

function loadProduct(product) {
    $('#product-display').empty();
    var desc = $('<div></div>').html(product.name + '<br/>' + product.desc);
    var btn = $('<button></button>').text('add').on('click', function() {
        addToCart(product);
    });
    $('#product-display').append(desc).append(btn);
}

function addToCart(product) {
    $('#cart').append($("<span></span>").text(product.name));
    $('#cart').append("<br/>")
};
```

The html:

```
<div id="products"></div>
<div id="product-display"></div>
<div id="cart"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12emhtx8/12/)